# Positioning div right to a already centered content without absolute position

Tags: css, height, positioning, center

I have two child divs (inline-block) inside a wrapper div. I want the left Div to be centered and the right one simply on the right of the left div.

```
<div id="Wrapper1"><div id="leftElement1">LEFT ELEMENT</div><div id="rightElement1">RIGHT</div></div>
```

The Problem is, if I use **margin-left** to reposition the whole wrapper, the Left Element is not centered on small screen sizes.

If I center *leftElement1* and use **position: absolute** to position *rightElement1* the Warpper Div does not adjust its width and height according to its children.

For a better understanding check http://jsfiddle.net/aaq810gs/6/

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to center the content of the left div, or the actual div itself?

Comment: This isn't very clear...

Comment: Do you mean like this - http://jsfiddle.net/78bt38sv/7/ NB. Requires the 'second' child to actually be a child of the 'first'

Comment: It's hard to explain, but I think @Paulie_D solved it. I'm double checking right now.

Comment: Unfortunately @Paulie_D's Solution won't work, because the wrapper won't adjust it's height to various hights of the left and right element.

Comment: I think it's possible that flexbox might solve this but the support isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Thank you for all your answers! Unfortunately I wasn't able to describe my Question properly, so none of the solutions worked.

Finally I was able to solve the problem myself. The Key to the solution was another centered outer wrapper, with a fixed size of the *to-be-centered Element* and **overflow: visible**. The inner content overlaps now the outer wrapper.

```
#outerWrapper {
  width: 700px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#Wrapper {
  width: 810px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aaq810gs/9/

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right you want something like this:

```
#rightElement1 {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    top: -100px;
}
```

Applied in your first example.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/78bt38sv/2/)

Or something like this:

```
#rightElement1 {
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/78bt38sv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if I get exactly what you mean, but I think something like this could work for you. 
- You better switch to **%**, because than it will work better on mobile devices. 
- Second thing is adding `margin:0 auto;` for #leftElement1 so it stays in the middle. #rightElement2 will just stick to it on the right, because it is inline-block. 
Now you can add whatever margin to the wrapper and it stays the same.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stassel/vzx6fm55/

HTML:

```
<div id="Wrapper1">
    <div id="leftElement1">LEFT ELEMENT</div>
    <div id="rightElement1">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Wrapper1 {
 width: 90%;
 background-color: red;
 margin: 0 auto;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-left:10%;}

#rightElement1 {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 10%;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 50px;}

#leftElement1 {
 background-color: green;
 width: 60%;
 margin:0 auto;
 display: inline-block;}

div {
 height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;}
```